# Output zipped directory to ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: java, servlets, file-io

I have a directory which I zip with this method:

```
 public byte[] archiveDir(File dir)  {
    try(ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
        zipSubDirectory("", dir, zout);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private void zipSubDirectory(String basePath, File dir, ZipOutputStream zout) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            String path = basePath + file.getName() + "/";
            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(path));
            zipSubDirectory(path, file, zout);
            zout.closeEntry();
        } else {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
            zout.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(basePath + file.getName()));
            int length;
            while ((length = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zout.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            zout.closeEntry();
            fin.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I then write the bytes to servlet's output stream. But when I receive the zip file, it cannot be opened "the file has wrong format". If I output zipped contents to FileOutputStream and then send file contents to servlet's output stream it works fine. Well, this would solve my problem but in this case I would always have to delete the temporary zip file after its contents are sent to servlet's outpu stream. Is it possible to do this just in memory.

Comment: "it cannot be opened" - What does this mean? How do you try to open it?

Comment: @HannoBinder It says, "the file has a wrong format". I updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hmm,

```
        zipSubDirectory(path, file, zout);
        zout.closeEntry();
```

should be:

```
        zout.closeEntry();
        zipSubDirectory(path, file, zout);
```

The main error seems to be that zout is not closed / flushed *before* toByteArray is called. Here try-with-resources was a bit devious.

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
    try ((ZipOutputStream zout = new ZipOutputStream(bos)) {
        zipSubDirectory("", dir, zout);
    }
    return bos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```